# Issue of react-smart-data-table in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-smart-data-table) data table. I import it like this `import SmartDataTable from 'react-smart-data-table'`. But I am getting below error.
[image]

Comment: Are you using Webpack to build your client?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisAdams. I am installed react using `npm create-react-app my-app`.

Comment: There's not much to go on, but it looks like create-react-app might not be able to pull in the icon for the table column.  I had a similar react problem last night and I only had to update my webpack config to load some font and icon files.  I haven't used create-react-app, but from looking through the docs, I came across a page that includes adding fonts, images, etc. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-images-fonts-and-files

Comment: Thanks @ChrisAdams for your reply. How can I solve the issue ?

Comment: Had you looked at the GitHub repo for this package (https://github.com/joaocarmo/react-smart-data-table)?  If you look at the issues, you'll see that this is a known issue with this package and create-react-app.  You're probably better off emailing the chap that wrote the table package.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisAdams . Is it better to leave this datatable ?

Comment: I can't answer that.  You need to decide what is best for your app.  You could easily craft your own table if you only want basic functionality to display a small number of rows.  You might want to google react table as there are lots of open source packages you could try.  Take a look at the NPM and GitHub pages for several of them.  See which ones suit your needs.  I also like to see how often a given package is download and updated.  Gives you an understanding of how good a package it is.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisAdams.